# Request model null in .NET core API if input json value integer

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have a situation, One of my API which was in .net WebAPI have converted to .NetCore API. The data flow architecture
is same for both i.e Controller is defined, Request comes through JSON & is binded to Model with all parameters in model
as string.

The issue here is for my old API ( Asp.net Web API) , one of my parameter MobileNo if I pass it in string or integer it accepts it
& process the flow further.

But in (.Net Core API ) it does not happens this way. If I pass Mobile no. in string it accepts the request.
but if numeric value is passed i get null object in Model.

Have provided below sample request which is accepted
& the one which is passed as null

Accepted request

```
{
"EmployeeCode":"1234"
"EmployeeName":"Test"
"MobileNo":"1234567890"
}
```

Null Model Passed for

```
{
"EmployeeCode":"1234"
"EmployeeName":"Test"
"MobileNo":1234567890
}
```

My model and controller code is below

```
public class EmpRequest 
    { 
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; } 
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(500)]
        public async Task<IActionResult>APIGetEmployee([FromBody] EmpRequest reqModel)
        {
}
```

I have tried to convert the value in controller

```
Convert.Tostring(reqModel.MobileNo )
```

but its not work as model itself coming is null in request.

Comment: You have to write your own `JsonConverter` and apply it to your property as attribute `JsonConverter(typeof(MyIntToStringConverter))`

Comment: Please correct your sample requests because none of them are valid json (commas are missing).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it uses `System.Text.Json` by default for JSON serialization and deserialization in ASP.NET Core 3.0+ project, and it does not allow non-string JSON values for string properties.

To achieve your requirement and fix the issue, as @Oliver mentioned in comment, you can try to implement and use a custom JsonConverter, like below.

```
public class ConverterForMobileNo : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            int value = reader.GetInt32();
            return value.ToString();
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            return reader.GetString();
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}
```

*Apply the jsonconverter*

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConverterForMobileNo))]
public string MobileNo { get; set; }
```

Besides, the Newtonsoft.Json seems allow non-string JSON values for string properties, you can also try to install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) NuGet package to add support for Newtonsoft.Json based features.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your model you take mobileno property as string and you wanted to pass int value to that property.
You can convert your model property MobileNo to Int if you want to pass Int on it.
as datavalue not matching when you passing object thats why it is returning null.